# 3 or Multiple Y-axis in dundas Chart ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, charts, dundas

Is it possible to use Multiple or 3 Y-axis in Dundas Chart?
If it is Possible than how to plot using Dundas Chart.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

One of the samples in the download has 3 or 4 y axes - essentially you create multiple chart areas that overlap each other with all but one being transparent - only the y axis shows from the transparent chart areas.

Microsoft acquired Dundas charts, so most code is interchangeable between the two.